# How to stop jQuery UI slider from overflowing on the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery UI Slider which goes a lot over from the right side.

How can I get it to stop at the same spot as it stops at the left?

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/gqb7z9tx/

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="slider-wrapper">
   <div id="slider">
    <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery**

```
  $( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) + " €" );
      },
      min: 1000,
      max: 1000000,
      step: 1000,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handle.text( ui.value + " €");
      }
    });
  } );
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-wrapper {
  padding: 50px;
}

  #custom-handle {
    width: 5em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
```

Comment: The width of your Handle causes it to bleed over. I would adjust it's Left Margin. This way it lands more to the middle of the handle.

Comment: Thanks! I added half of the width as negative left margin to the handle and now it goes 50% of the width over from both sides. I'm just wondering if there's any way to stop the handle from overflowing on either side.

Comment: There is not a good way to do that. You can make the handle smaller and then float and move the label above the handle. In this way you get your full range of motion on the slider, but the label does not overflow the slider.